# how to place admob ad in seperate container at bottom of app?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, mobile, admob

I have added admob to my app and placed the ad at the bottom of the page.... hoever it covers the web content that i need people to see.... is there anyway to place the ad in a separate container or frame at the bottom of the screen so that the content stops where the ad begins?

here is my xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.payforlikes.app.payforlikes.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-4075500144464557/1187222817"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to rearrange your XML as follows:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ID"/>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/adView />
```

You move the `WebView` below the `AdView` in your XML so you can reference the `AdView`'s ID, and then, using your `RelativeLayout`, you can restrict the `WebView` to be above the `AdView`.

Comment: how would i resrtrict WebView to be above the AdView in RelativeLayout?

Comment: never mind i got it to work, i didnt notice you removed my ad - id